# Dielectric polarization - should not the dimensions of the polarised dielectric increase in the direction of the field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization, dielectric

In the classical model for polarization, if a dielectric is placed in a an electrical field (assumed to be static for the sake of simplicity), the trajectory of the electrons inside the atoms of the dielectric is modified. Assuming for the sake of simplicity that the atoms are normally roughly spherical, the trajectory becomes elliptic, and the atoms become roughly ellipsoids.

I wonder why the dimension of the dielectric does not increase in the direction of the electrical field, in a proportion equal to the proportion of the natural atom radius to the great axis of this ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1):

In general this effect is negligible because external electric fields are small at atomic scale. There is a class of materials, [piezoelectrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity), with a significant coupling between lattice and external electric field. Piezoelectric devices are widely used to light gas flames in household appliances for their ability to transform mechanical energy into a spark.

Comment: Is this effect negligible because the proportion of the great axis to the spherical radius is very close to 1, or because of something else ?